# How can I feed bytes to video memory from another location in 16 bit assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, 16-bit

I have stored specific data on memory location **0x4000**. I wanted to pass a byte from there to memory location **0xb800** so that the data is printed in the screen. The problem arises when I try to store in **0xb800:0** what would be my first byte that I assume is in **0x4000:0**. The code I used as example is below:

```
mov ax, 0xb800
mov es, ax
mov byte [es:0], 'A'
```

This compiles fine and runs perfectly, but what I'm trying to adapt throws an "**invalid segment override**" error on NASM. Here is my non working code:

```
mov ax, 0xb800
mov es, ax
mov byte [es:0], byte [0x4000:0]
```

Is it possible to get a single byte from 0x4000:[offset] and feed it to 0xb800:[offset] by using ES segment? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but you can't do it in a single instruction like you have. You'll need to use another segment register, such as `ds`, plus an intermediate register (`al` here):

```
mov ax, 0x4000
mov ds, ax
mov ax, 0xb800
mov es, ax
mov al, [ds:0]
mov [es:0], al
```

Note that if you've got `ds` pointed somewhere else, then you'll have consider that too (such as by saving and restoring it).